# Get working but post not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, get

I was stuck by an annoying problem in my code but solved but confused me. I am using `DATE FROM`----`DATE TO` boxes to select range of date to display employees between that date ranges in `WEBGRID` but problem was that in first display it appears exactly according to that date ranges but when i do pagination (clicking page 2, 3 , 4....) then it picked all employees record for every date because i have set IF condition like that if `DatFrom` and `TO` are empty then pick all results like i mentioned in `IF` block. It all was due to `FORMMETHOD.POST`, when i wrote `FORMMETHOD.GET` then it started working correctly, WHY ?

so how to implement it correctly ?

```
public ActionResult ShowCalTextBox(String DateFrom, String DateTo)
        {

            if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo == "")
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_DateFrom = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, null).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records for"+" "+ DateFrom ;
                return View(EmpRec_DateFrom);

            }
            else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo != "")
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_DateTo = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(null, DateTo).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records for" + " " + DateTo;
                return View(EmpRec_DateTo);
            }
            else if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo != "")
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_ByDate = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, DateTo).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records from" + " " + DateFrom +" "+"to"+" "+DateTo;
                return View(EmpRec_ByDate);
            }
            else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo == "")
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_Default = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(null, null).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "No date selection";
                return View(EmpRec_Default);
            }

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

VIEW:

```
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowCalTextBox", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
  <label id="lblFrom">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="TxtBoxFrom" name="DateFrom" />
  <label id="lblTo">To</label>
  <input type="text" id="TxtBoxTo" name="DateTo"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitDate" name="btnSubmit">Submit</button>  
}
</div>

<div>
 <h4>@ViewBag.Dates</h4>
 <br />
 @{

     var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, rowsPerPage: 20, canPage: false);

  }

 <div id="AllEmpGrid_ByDate">
   @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                                        grid.Column("EmplID", "Employee ID"),
                                        grid.Column("EmplName","Employee Name"),
                                        grid.Column("ShiftID", "Shift ID"),
                                        grid.Column("DateVisited", "Date of Visit"),
                                        grid.Column("InTime", "In Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TimeOut", "Time Out"),
                                        grid.Column("OverTime", "Over Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TotalWorkingTime", "Total Working Time")    
                                      ))
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I assume you have `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes in the appropriate places ... ?

Comment: i didn't mentioned attributes explicitly, But when i changed FORM method to GET then it worked but now with post, with post it forgets dates being selected, DURING PAGINATION

Comment: i think reason is that in POST values are send after body so in first place it executes IF because values are empty but in GET it receives values in first attempt because send in header ? right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is very simple. You have an html `<form>` in which you have placed the start and end date input fields. The grid on the other hand is completely separate. If you use POST, then the values entered in those textboxes are sent in the body of the request and are not seen in the current url. So when the WebGrid renders, it cannot generate correct values for the pagination links. The reason for this is because when it generates those links it includes all query string parameters that are part of the current request url.

On the other hand, when you switch your form to use GET verb, then the values of the textboxes become part of the current url as query string parameters and when the WebGrid renders the pagination links it picks them up. That's the proper way to implement this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowCalTextBox", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    ...
}
```

If you use POST, the WebGrid has absolutely no way of knowing that you have some other html `<form>` in your page and pick cannot pick the values.

Comment: great sir, lemme summarize what i understood of your post, i think reason is that in POST values are send after body so in first place it executes IF because values are empty but in GET it receives values in first attempt because send in header ? right ?

Comment: Your understanding is almost correct. It's just that when you make a GET requests the values are sent as query string parameters in the url (not in headers as you wrote in your comment). The values are visible in the current url after submitting the form. Just look at the address bar of your browser.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean that. A POST request sends the values in the body of the request.

Comment: So if it sends values then why it doesn't execute